# Why Real time report not showing when manual instead of automatic screen measurement in Google Analytics for Android App?

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics

After setting up of Google Mobile Analytics in my Android App, I like to measure Screen Views using Google analytics.
I follow the instructions from this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/screens

According to this link, I tried to change "Screen View" name in my code. 
But, Active users on "Real Time" refresh and shows the number for Automatics screen measurement instead of manual screen measurement. Also, Screen view name doesn't change even I changed the name in the code.
These manual changes only refresh in "Audience" report, not in Real Time reports.

Appreciated if somebody can help me how to get Real Time data when Manual screen view measurement.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

The real-time data that they talk about is just a bit delayed. You can watch the number of users currently active on the app. However, the events are displayed with about 5-10 minutes of delay.

Comment: Thanks for your comments..
In the case of "Automatic measurement", Real time data is displayed without delay, it just takes a few seconds only.
When I changed to Manual (Code changes), it doesn't show in Real time.